# Flink serialization of java.util.List and java.util.Map

Tags: java, apache-flink

My Flink pipeline currently uses an Pojo that contains some Lists and Maps (of Strings), along the lines of

```
public class MyPojo {
    private List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    private OtherPojo otherPojo = new OtherPojo();

    // getters + setters...
}

public class OtherPojo {
    private Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();

    // getters + setters...
}
```

For performance reasons, I want to get around Kryo serialization, so I disabled the generic fallback with `env.getConfig().disableGenericTypes();` as described in the [Flink documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/types_serialization.html).

Now, Flink complains about the lists:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Generic types have been disabled in the ExecutionConfig and type java.util.List is treated as a generic type.
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.GenericTypeInfo.createSerializer(GenericTypeInfo.java:86)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.PojoTypeInfo.createPojoSerializer(PojoTypeInfo.java:319)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.PojoTypeInfo.createSerializer(PojoTypeInfo.java:311)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraph.addOperator(StreamGraph.java:258)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator.transformOneInputTransform(StreamGraphGenerator.java:649)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator.transform(StreamGraphGenerator.java:250)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator.generate(StreamGraphGenerator.java:209)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.getStreamGraph(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1540)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1507)
    ...
```

What is the preferred way of serializing such simple lists and maps in Flink?. Internally, these are currently `ArrayList` and `HashMap`, but other implementations would also be fine. There seems to be a class `org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer` in Flink, but I do not know how to use it.

Comment: Could you share your pojo?

Comment: @ArvidHeise I added the pojo to the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Marius already explained the reason beautifully, although I don't see the reason why Flink does not support your use case out of the box. Nevertheless, I'll add the solution that works right now.

```
// create type info
final TypeInformation<OtherPojo> otherPojoInfo = Types.POJO(OtherPojo.class, 
    ImmutableMap.of("myMap", Types.MAP(Types.STRING, Types.STRING)));
final TypeInformation<MyPojo> myPojoInfo = Types.POJO(MyPojo.class,
    ImmutableMap.of("myList", Types.LIST(Types.STRING), "otherPojo", otherPojoInfo));

// test it
final MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo();
myPojo.getMyList().add("test");
myPojo.getOtherPojo().getMyMap().put("ping", "pong");

final TypeSerializer<MyPojo> serializer = myPojoInfo.createSerializer(env.getConfig());
DataOutputSerializer dataOutputSerializer = new DataOutputSerializer(100);
serializer.serialize(myPojo, dataOutputSerializer);

DataInputDeserializer dataInputDeserializer = new DataInputDeserializer(dataOutputSerializer.getSharedBuffer());
final MyPojo clone = serializer.deserialize(dataInputDeserializer);
assert(myPojo.equals(clone));
```

Note that the terrible access pattern in the test code is just for a quick and dirty demonstration.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. To make the type information known to Flink, I used a `@TypeInfo`-annotation. Now everything works and my serialization is much faster...

Comment: @AlexKrauss I'm missing how the manually created serializers can be registered with flink. The example above uses them explicitly. How to tell Flink to use them for a given type?

Comment: @summerian It is described here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/types_serialization.html#defining-type-information-using-a-factory
Basically, you use the `@TypeInfo` annotation on the Pojo, and reference a TypeInfoFactory class, which defines the serializers.

Comment: @AlexKrauss thanks a lot for your response. Can the line `env.getConfig().disableGenericTypes();` be used now, or does it still throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`? I've tried annotating a type containing a List with my custom factory, returning a POJO type, but the exception is still being thrown. I still need to measure whether performance improves or not.

Comment: @summerian IIRC, `disableGenericTypes` should then no longer throw an error. It may point you to something else that is still wrong...

Comment: @AlexKrauss I can confirm that, it is possible to have lists with serializers defined as above, and the `disableGenericTypes` does not throw an exception. Serialization seems to be a few times faster now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If you do:

```java
env.getConfig().disableGenericTypes();
```

It will raise an exception whenever a data type is encountered that would go through Kryo.

So in that case you have to write your own Serializer.
Which can be created using `TypeSerializer`, simply call `typeInfo.createSerializer(config)` on the TypeInformation object.

For generic types, you need to “capture” the generic type information via the TypeHint, in your case for a list:

```java
TypeInformation<List<Object>> info = TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<List<Object>>(){});
```

[ListTypeInfo class](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/typeutils/ListTypeInfo.html)

More details in [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/types_serialization.html#creating-a-typeinformation-or-typeserializer).