# Flink Serialization of java.util.Set

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm having the same issue as described by [Flink serialization of java.util.List and java.util.Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59800851/flink-serialization-of-java-util-list-and-java-util-map), but for `java.util.Set`.

I have a POJO class that has `List` fields and `Set` fields. I've been able to POJO serialize the `List` fields by following the solution in the above link, but it seems like there is no support for `Set` in the TypeInfo library: https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/typeinfo/Types.java#L438

I'm wondering if this is a known issue, if there's a solution in an upcoming Flink version (I'm on 16.1.1), or if anyone knows a workaround.

In the mean time, it is okay that I only POJO serialize the List and basic fields, but I would like to register my Set field for POJO serialization as well as it is a heavy field. I would also like to enable `env.getConfig().disableGenericTypes();` on production but having a `Set` field is preventing this.

Comment: Maybe because there is no `Set` datatype when serializing from-to JSON? I assume you would have to use a `List` instead.